# Sum of a list in Mathematica

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

In mathematica how would I find the sum of a list plugged into a function such as

```
(15*(1-D)) when D=[0,.05,.065,.08,.10,.12,.14,.16,.18,.20]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
PP = {0, .05, .065, .08, .10, .12, .14, .16, .18, .20};
Plus @@ 15*(1 - PP)
```

Couple of things to remember: `D` is a reserved function for `Derivative`. Generally speaking, avoid variables names starting with uppercase letters. Next, `Array`s are defined using `{}`